# React Native, run js script in background

Tags: react-native

Please help me to show a simple way to run an JS script in background on both iOS and Android, and update the JS script (file) from remote server?

This is what I am truing to do.

1. Run JS-file (function) in background
2. Start/stop function from WebView
3. Download updated version of the JS-file

Can anyone help me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you want to update the JS bundle react-native uses?

Comment: I my dream, I like to update one or more js files. I will use themthat then I will use in my WebView.